# OpenVPN is connected but not accesing VPN LAN network

Tags: openvpn

I had configured a OpenVPN server on Ubuntu 14.04

I had clients connecting to my VPN server and works fine.
 But when a client having LAN with network range same as on server side its gets connected but not accessing to my local VPN server LAN.

My VPN server LAN nw-192.168.1.0/24

My client office n/w-192.168.1.0/24

So I can't find solution to my problem..

Please consider me as a learner and having little knowledge for server and networking...

Comment: I can't change the subnet...

Comment: "_I had configured openvpn server_" Can't you configure again?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: change to a different subnet

Comment: Does anyone have other solution

Answer (score 0):

If the two networks use the same IP range, you'll have trouble making them collaborate.

One (ugly) solution is to use NAT on one of the VPN endpoints in order to map the IP addresses of one of the networks into a different/non-conflicting range.

Comment: Thanx mate. This is something i wanted to know.

Comment: i s there any other solution than changing subnet